# How to make menu slide from Viewport to the Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning (just began) jQuery and now I want to make a menu like on [this site](http://gothemes.net/html/rise/#about)

I mean, I want the menu to slide down out of the viewport to the header, just like in template in the link.

I tried to look at jQuery API documentation, some videos on YT about menus etc, but I did not find anything relevant.

Can anyone please learn me, how to do this?

Thank you very much

PS: I just have this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #4E4F53;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul.active {}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1.25em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu-toggle {
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>RISE</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".menu").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `translateY();` css class and jQuery to toggle classes.

This code snippet should get you where you need to be! It will need a bit of editing to fit your needs.

I've added a div called `.offsite-canvas` that houses your "offscreen" container. When you press the menu toggle button, jQuery toggles a class that puts the offscreen container in view for the user.

```js
$( ".menu-toggle" ).click(function() {
    $(".offsite-canvas").toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.offsite-canvas {
position: relative;
transform: translateY(-400px);
transition: all .5s;
z-index: 100;
}

.offsite-canvas.open {
position: relative;
transform: translateY(0);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #4E4F53;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul.offcanvas {
display: flex;
float: none;
z-index: 100;
}

ul.active {}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1.25em;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.menu-toggle {
  margin: 0 1em;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>RISE</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<div class="offsite-canvas">
      <ul class="offcanvas">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>

  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
      </div>
      <div class="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".menu").toggle();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much...this is what i have looking for :) thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest if you want to make a nav menu that comes onto the screen when a button is clicked, create the menus as normal, and then place it off the screen on either the left or the right by using `translateX()` in css.

From that point on, when the button is clicked, Toggle a class that would translate the menu one the x axis so that it is visible.